# Matching a string with out matching a specific word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression to match a string but exclude a specific words from the string.
for example

```
dfm HSBC12323
```

i need to extract

```
HSBC12323
```

and do not include `dfm`. if the string `HSBC12323` it need to match it as it is as `dfm` may not be exist.

if the string `dfm123213` i need to match `123213`
`adx 212321` i need to match `212321` not `adx`
`adx hsbc123uy` i need to match `hsbc123uy` 
`hsbc1237` i need to match it as is.

```
(?<!dfm\s*?|adx\s*?|\w)\d+
```

but it doesn't work like i want

```
Actual string : dfm HSBC12323  excpected HSBC12323 
Actual string : HSBC12323  expected HSBC12323 
Actual string : dfm123213 expected 123213
Actual string : adx 212321 expected 212321 
Actual string : usa1237 expected usa1237
```

Comment: If these are standalone strings, try `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?:dfm|adx)\s*", "")`

Comment: is `HSBC` the only leading string of non-digits that you expect?

Comment: how would you expect usa1237 to be outputted?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no it can be any 3 or 4 characters

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i dont want to use replace , i need to match it

Comment: @BugFinder if the input is usa1237 i need to output to be the same.

Comment: @BugFinder if the input is dfm usa1237 i need the output to be usa1237,

Comment: You could match it using an optional capturing group `(?:dfm|adx)? *(\w+)` See https://regex101.com/r/Tnex1G/1

Comment: @user2120457 (actually your example was only use1237, no dfm) that but you didnt want it if its dfm123213 .. so how are you defining what is good what is bad

Comment: What are the matching rules then?

Comment: Or use a combination of a lookahead and a lookbehind `(?<=(?:dfm|adx) *)\w+|\b(?!(?:dfm|adx))\w+` See a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%28%3f%3adfm%7cadx%29+*%29%5cw%2b%7c%5cb%28%3f!%28%3f%3adfm%7cadx%29%29%5cw%2b&i=dfm+HSBC12323%0d%0aHSBC12323%0d%0adfm123213%0d%0aadx+212321%0d%0aadx+hsbc123uy%0d%0ahsbc1237)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `(?<!dfm\s*?|adx\s*?|\w)\d+` matches 1+ digits if what is on the left is not either dfm or adx or a word character where after the first 2 there can be whitespace chars. You don't have to make the `s*?` non greedy as it can not pass matching the following digits `\d+`

In all your examples that would not match because before all the examples `\w` can match before a digit when the first 2 can not match. This for example `$22` would match.

One option to match your values could be using a alternation in combination with a positive lookbehind and a negative lookahead.

```
(?<=\b(?:dfm|adx) *)\w+|\b(?!(?:dfm|adx))\w+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left

  - `\b(?:dfm|adx) *` Word boundary, match either dfm or adx followed by 0+ times a space
- `)` Close positive lookbehind
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `|` Or
- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not

  - `(?:dfm|adx)` Match either dfm or adx
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

See a .NET [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%28%3f%3adfm%7cadx%29+*%29%5cw%2b%7c%5cb%28%3f!%28%3f%3adfm%7cadx%29%29%5cw%2b&i=dfm+HSBC12323%0d%0aHSBC12323%0d%0adfm123213%0d%0aadx+212321%0d%0aadx+hsbc123uy%0d%0ahsbc1237%0d%0ausa1237%0d%0a)

You might also add `(?!\S)` after matching `\w+` if the match should not be followed by a non whitespace char.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that with this expression or one similar to, we can just step by step capture what we desire to, and then we can even strengthen our expression with additional constraints, just to be safe:

```
(?=dfm\s+|adx\s+)(?:dfm\s+([A-Z0-9]+)|adx\s+([0-9]+))|(?=dfm)dfm([0-9]+)|[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A9RIlY/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?=dfm\s+|adx\s+)(?:dfm\s+([A-Z0-9]+)|adx\s+([0-9]+))|(?=dfm)dfm([0-9]+)|[A-Za-z0-9]+";
        string input = @"dfm HSBC12323
HSBC12323
dfm123213
adx 212321
usa1237";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]